# Animating D3 Arc in React interpolating wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

I have `react` component, I have created 3 arcs with `3`, I wanted to animate this arcs with `attrTween`. But it's not working at all, I have created method `arcTween` this takes 3 arguments; old angles, new angles, and, arc `function` but it's not properly interpolate the values and not creating `d` value while transitioning.

```
import React, { createRef, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { select, arc, interpolate, interval } from "d3";

import "./styles.css";

function arcTween(oldData, newData, _arc) {
  const copy = { ...oldData };
  return function() {
    const interpolateStartAngle = interpolate(
        oldData.startAngle,
        newData.startAngle
      ),
      interpolateEndAngle = interpolate(oldData.endAngle, newData.endAngle);

    return function(t) {
      copy.startAngle = interpolateStartAngle(t);
      copy.endAngle = interpolateEndAngle(t);
      return _arc(interpolateStartAngle(t), interpolateEndAngle(t));
    };
  };
}

function App() {
  const svgRef = createRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (svgRef.current) {
      const svg = select(svgRef.current);
      const p = Math.PI / 2;

      const arc1 = arc()
        .innerRadius(130)
        .outerRadius(140)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .endAngle(-1.2)
        .startAngle(1);

      const arc2 = arc()
        .innerRadius(130)
        .outerRadius(140)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .startAngle(1.2)
        .endAngle(3.4);

      const arc3 = arc()
        .innerRadius(130)
        .outerRadius(140)
        .startAngle(3.6)
        .cornerRadius(20)
        .endAngle(5);

      const one = svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc1)
        .attr("transform", "translate(300,200)")
        .attr("fill", "#ffff00");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc2)
        .attr("transform", "translate(300,200)");

      svg
        .append("path")
        .attr("d", arc3)
        .attr("transform", "translate(300,200)");
    }
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <svg ref={svgRef} width="600" height="400" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

you can check running application [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-montalcini-9r2jp)